# How to determine outcome of FreeSWITCH bridge application?

Tags: freeswitch

I am stuck in unique situation. I am using httapi module. In response to one of the httapi request I am sending the following response, which execute bridge application and calls the user. It works fine.

```
<document type="xml/freeswitch-httapi">
  <params>
    ${someContext}
  </params>
  <variables>
    <call_timeout>10</call_timeout>
  </variables>
  <work>
    <execute application="bridge" data="${to}" />
  </work>
</document>
```

After bridge app execution completes, freeswitch send another httapi request asking what execute next? In this phase I want to find out status of last executed bridge application and based on that determine the next action, for example.

1. If timeout happened?
2. If hung up after answer?
3. If hung up before answer?

But I could not determine answer to above questions give that I am getting limited data in the httapi body as follows .

```
{
  session_id: '',
  method: 'POST',
  url: '',
  hostname: '',
  'Caller-Direction': '',
  'Caller-Logical-Direction': '',
  'Caller-Username': '',
  'Caller-Dialplan': '',
  'Caller-Caller-ID-Name': '',
  'Caller-Caller-ID-Number': '',
  'Caller-Orig-Caller-ID-Name': '',
  'Caller-Orig-Caller-ID-Number': '',
  'Caller-Network-Addr': '',
  'Caller-ANI': '',
  'Caller-ANI-II': '',
  'Caller-Destination-Number': '',
  'Caller-Unique-ID': '',
  'Caller-Source': '',
  'Caller-Context': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Name': '',
  'Caller-Profile-Index': '',
  'Caller-Profile-Created-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Created-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Answered-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Progress-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Progress-Media-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Hangup-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Transfer-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Resurrect-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Bridged-Time': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Last-Hold': '',
  'Caller-Channel-Hold-Accum': '',
  'Caller-Screen-Bit': '',
  'Caller-Privacy-Hide-Name': '',
  'Caller-Privacy-Hide-Number': '',
}
```

Is there a way to get the status of previously executed app (bridge) in httapi.